# Processing text to build a dictionary in java with just arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a beginner in java and I've just started working on data mining. I'm building a program which proccesses a piece of text (article.txt file), it displays the original words of article.txt (e.g. regardless of how many times the word 'the' appears, it will only be shown once) and also shows the number of occurence of the original words (e.g. 'the' occurs 120 times).

The idea is to try and summarise the text data and allow someone to understand it by looking at the words with the most occurences. I feel that my problem lies in finding the original words.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("article.txt"));
        int bufferLength = 1000000;
        char[] buffer = new char[bufferLength];
        int charsRead = br.read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        br.close();
        String text = new String(buffer);
        text = text.toLowerCase();
        String[] words = text.split(" ");

        int z = 0;

        // # OF WORDS IN TEXT
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            words[i] = words[i].trim();
        } 
        System.out.println("There are " + words.length + " words in this text.");


        String[] uniqueWordArray = new String[412]; // To store unique words
        int[] uniqueWordArrayCount = new int[z]; // To store # of unique words

        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            // char[] convertedText = text.toCharArray();

            // FINDING UNIQUE WORDS AND ADDING THEM TO AN ARRAY
            if(Arrays.asList(text).contains(words[i]) && !Arrays.asList(uniqueWordArray).contains(words[i])) { 

                int x = (int)(Math.random()*211);
                uniqueWordArray[x] = words[i];
                z++; // see uWACount value
            }
            else { 
               z++;
                } 
        }
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(uniqueWordArray));
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(uniqueWordArrayCount));
```

Honestly, I don't know where I'm going wrong in terms of finding the unique/original words, I wrote some pseudocode after several attempts:

```
For every word in text
        if word exists in original/unique word array
            Increment corresponding count in unique word count array 
        else
            Add new unique word in original/unique word array
            Increment corresponding count in unique word count array
```

Any suggestions? And what do you think I did wrong in my original code?

**NOTE:** The current answers are referring to use different imports and libraries, I'm trying to use arrays (perhaps 2D arrays) to solve this problem and no lists, hash tables etc. as I've seen similar programs like this by other novices with just arrays plus I've spent days trying to figure this out so I'd feel guilty. I understand it is a restriction but I feel I can become better if I tackle the challenge with it.

Comment: Do you have some error or unexpected output?

Comment: @Abdelhak Yes, I get an array of essentially 'null' in number format (the numbers in a slot of an array) printed out 412 times.

Comment: Any particular reason, why you insist on using arrays? Sets and HashMaps are the way to go here. Insisting on arrays would be like insisting on climbing Mount Everest bare foot. It just makes no sense.

Comment: Your implementation is also bit weird as you create a new List for every check whether the array contains the word.

Comment: @Ridcully I'm on a java 4 beginners course and it says I should use what I've learned so far from the course to build the dictionary plus other novices have completed the task with arrays so I didn't think it'd be that hard. Oh well, thanks for trying though!

Comment: @Kalicz thanks, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: A dictionary, by definition, is a (hash-) map. Emulating a map with just an array is highly inefficient. `Arrays.asList().contains` is about the *worst* choice you could have made. Storing words at a random position in your array is also absurd.

Comment: @SteveGates I see, but doing the task without Lists and Maps is much more difficult, as basically you have to invent your own data structures, whilest those have already been invented and perfected by software geniuses like Donald Knuth or the "Gang of Four", so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people have suggested a few ways you can improve your code and make it easier, e.g. by using the [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface. This will be advantageous in many ways when you loop through a file, as there are already built in methods for comparison purposes (so you can increment a lastSeenCount as you compare, for example). Also you won't need to define the size of the list initially (differently to arrays, which are fixed in size), so it won't matter how many words the file has as the program starts.

Now as to why your program isn't working as per what you're expecting - let's take a look at the if statement below:

```
if(Arrays.asList(text).contains(words[i]) && !Arrays.asList(uniqueWordArray).contains(words[i])) { 
    int x = (int)(Math.random()*211);
    uniqueWordArray[x] = words[i];
    z++; // see uWACount value
}
else {
    z++;
}
```

When you run your program, it *appears* that you're getting all nulls and that's because of the following:

```
int x = (int)(Math.random()*211);
uniqueWordArray[x] = words[i];
```

Your integer 'x' is using a random number (multiplied by 211) to store the word you're looping through within the uniqueWordArray. The thing is: that random number may or may not be within the first few entries of the array (as it's random, you can't control it).

So, actually, it isn't that you're getting all nulls - but really that the words are spread around within the array (I don't know how many words you have in article.txt, but especially if not many then you might not notice that you actually have added them successfully).

The reason you're getting so many nulls is because the array has fixed size and, when you create the array, they are all null entries until you tell your program to populate these:

```
String[] uniqueWordArray = new String[412]; // To store unique words
```

So, a way to discover the problem would be to check where the words are actually being stored with a simple:

```
System.out.println("Result of the calculation is " + x)
System.out.println("The word being stored is " + words[i]);
```

As I mentioned, the way you implemented is obviously not ideal - but I hope this helps solve the mystery as to why the program isn't working as you expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use java.io.StreamTokenizer to read words from the file and store them in Map where you can also keep count of them.

```
    StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("article.txt"))));
    st.whitespaceChars(' ', '/');
    st.wordChars('a', 'Z');
    Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    int token;
    do {
        token = st.nextToken();
        if (token == StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD) {
            String word = st.sval.toLowerCase();
            int count = 0;
            if (wordMap.containsKey(word))
                count = wordMap.get(word);
            wordMap.put(word, count + 1);
        }
    }
    while (token != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF);

    for (String word : wordMap.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(word + ": " + wordMap.get(word));
    }
```

If you really insist on not using HashMap, here is implementation using just plain Array. However it is way less effective.

```
    StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("article.txt"))));
    st.whitespaceChars(' ', '/');
    st.wordChars('a', 'Z');

    int maxSize = 400;
    String[] words = new String[maxSize];
    int[] counts = new int[maxSize];
    int length = 0;
    int token;
    do {
        token = st.nextToken();
        if (token == StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD) {
            String word = st.sval.toLowerCase();
            boolean newWord = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                if (words[i].equals(word))
                {
                    counts[i]++;
                    newWord = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (newWord) {
                words[length] = word;
                counts[length] = 1;
                length++;
            }
        }
    }
    while (token != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        System.out.println(words[i] + ": " + counts[i]);
    }
```

It does not check max length of array, so you need to verify it before adding a value into it and create a bigger array if needed. It is very uneffective implementation.

Answer (score 1):

to find unique words, put them all in a Set

to find occurrences of each word, use for example a Map and increment (with that, it replaces also the Set)